# is safari putting in history only pages tha are complete loaded?

Tags: macos, safari, browser-history

am facing a very wired issue,
in mac safari i've noticed if you click link on a page that is not complete loaded, lets say that the page we are on is A and the link we are clicking will drive us to page B, so we click it and now we are in page B.

remember we clicked the link before the page A is complete loaded.

from this point if click browser back button you would expect to return to page A, right, but instead you go to browsers start page with the favorites.

am asking just to confirm that this is the expected behavior, that if a page is not complete loaded it wont get in the safari's history list?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is about programming and not general computer usage. You should delete the question and ask it at SuperUser instead.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch am not asking just for general knowledge I he tried to handle this issue by coding but I always end up in dead end so I posted here if some had something that could help me. anyway how can I ask/post this to a SuperUser. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The history is a Javascript's object for:

```
 manipulating the browser session history, (pages "visited" in the tab or frame that the current page is loaded in).
```

It's on document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history.
it's mean that the browser will store the url that is loaded completely.

I think.

Comment: thanks for the reply

but am still wondering why this is not happening in chrome (mac OSX always)!!!